# Trying to use QStackedLayout with QStacked:: StackAll, but it works incorrectly

Tags: qt

I am trying to use a QStackedLayout with QStacked:: StackAll, to display two widgets at the same time. But, even when I put a transparent background, it breaks through the widget that is under the main one.

The white background next to the blue circle is a button that sits on another widget:
[image: The white background next to the blue circle is a button that sits on another widget]

This is my mainwindow.cpp code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "mywidget.h"

#include <QStackedLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    MyWidget* wg = new MyWidget(this);

    FirstWidget* fw = new FirstWidget;
    SecondWidget* sw = new SecondWidget;

    QStackedLayout* stack = new QStackedLayout;
    stack->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);

    stack->addWidget(sw);
    stack->addWidget(fw);

    wg->setLayout(stack);

    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton(this);
    btn->setFixedSize(100, 20);


    btn->setText("Check");
    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [stack]()
    {
       if (stack->currentIndex() == 0)
       {
           stack->setCurrentIndex(1);
           qDebug() << "fw";
       }
       else
       {
           stack->setCurrentIndex(0);
           qDebug() << "sw";
       }

    });
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is wrong? "it breaks through the widget that is under the main one" is not very clear. What is your end goal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make transparent background for topmost widget in the stack SecondWidget or FirstWidget, but you call setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground) for MainWindow. You can also try sw->setStyleSheet("background : transparent;").